# Controller gives directory browsing rather than returning text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have the following action method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string filename)
    {

        string detailFolder = SSOSettingsFileManager.SSOSettingsFileReader.ReadString("bts.go.core", "SupportNotificationDetailPath");

        string pathFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(detailFolder, filename);

        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(pathFile);
        XNamespace ns = "http://BTS.GO.Core.Schemas.SupportNotificationDetail";

        var notificationMsg = from x in xdoc.Descendants("NotificationMessage") select x.Value;
        var content = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(notificationMsg.FirstOrDefault());
        IHtmlString htmlContent = new HtmlString(content);

        SupportNotificationDetailViewModel vm = new SupportNotificationDetailViewModel();
        vm.Content = htmlContent;

        return View(vm);
}
```

This works fine when deployed into my dev machine.The view calls the action and is returned the text content of the "NotificationMessage"element, which it renders on screen, as shown below:

[image]

My problem is, with the same site deployed to my test server. When I click the link that executes the action, rather than being presented with text, I get a directory listing of the content of the folder contained in the variable detailFolder, as shown below:

[image]

I guess this must be down to a difference in the IIS config. I tried using [msdn link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2014/09/12/iis-server-and-site-comparison-with-web-deploy/) to figure it out but no luck. The command for msdeploy comes back with "Cannot create a file when that file already exists.". I find this strange because I used web deploy to deploy the website to both servers. Both machines are running server 2012r2

The bad server has the following Windows Features installed (should be all that's needed?):
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: you probably don't have Asp.Net framework installed on the server

Comment: Make sure your app pool does use the right framework

Comment: App pool is .net 4 with integrated pipeline

Comment: Have you verified that ASP.Net is fully enabled under the Turn Windows features on or off | IIS | World Wide Web Services | Application Development Features? Installing the framework doesn't automatically enable the development bits (changed in Win 2008).

Comment: I think so, see latest screenshot just added

Comment: Might have to also run: aspnet_regiis.exe -ir .

Comment: @RobBowman That IIS feature configuration looks correct. It's odd though that it is serving the directory contents. By default that is turned off in IIS.